# Mixins not working with dart-sass in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have installed `sass` package in the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sass--kedl7?file=/scss/main.scss) which is just simple CRA with `sass` package installed.
In `src/scss/main.scss` file I have code like:

```
@use './partials/mixins' as *;
body{
  @include mq2;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

and in the `src/scss/partials/mixins.scss` file I have code like:

```
@mixin mq2{
    background: pink;
}
```

I am trying to use a simple mixin in sass in CRA but it throws errror like:

```
Error: no mixin named mq2
        on line 9:12 of /stdin
>>   @include mq2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proble is with codesandbox environment as I tested same code locally and it works without any such errors.